# Unable to fix my Navbar in Next JS TypeScript App

Tags: typescript, next.js, tailwind-css, navbar, tailwind-elements

I just created my first Next JS TypeScript App using Tailwind. I am using Tailwind Elements library to add NavBar. However, it is showing in column and i'm unable to fix it to display it in row. Please guide me so that i may fix my navbar. Thanks

src/global.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


.navbar {
  background-color: var(--dark);
  color: #fff;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100vw;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 12px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px; 
  left: 0px;
}

:root {
  --foreground-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
  --background-start-rgb: 214, 219, 220;
  --background-end-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  :root {
    --foreground-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
    --background-start-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
    --background-end-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
  }
}

body {
  color: rgb(var(--foreground-rgb));
  background: 
  linear-gradient(
      to bottom,
      transparent,
      rgb(var(--background-end-rgb))
    )
    rgb(var(--background-start-rgb));
}
```

src/layout.tsx

```
import { NavBar, Footer } from '@/components'
import './globals.css'
import type { Metadata } from 'next'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
}

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <NavBar />
        {children}
        <Footer />
        </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

src/page.tsx

```
import Image from "next/image";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main className='flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24'>

      {/* <!-- Hero section with background image, heading, subheading and button --> */}
      <div
        className='relative overflow-hidden bg-cover bg-no-repeat'
        style={{
          backgroundPosition: "50%",
          backgroundImage:
            "url('https://tecdn.b-cdn.net/img/new/slides/146.webp')",
          height: "350px",
        }}
      >
        <div
          className='absolute bottom-0 left-0 right-0 top-0 h-full w-full overflow-hidden bg-fixed'
          style={{ backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)" }}
        >
          <div className='flex h-full items-center justify-center'>
            <div className='px-6 text-center text-white md:px-12'>
              {/* <h1 className='mb-6 text-5xl font-bold'>Heading</h1>
              <h3 className='mb-8 text-3xl font-bold'>Subeading</h3>
              <button
                type='button'
                className='inline-block rounded border-2 border-neutral-50 px-6 pb-[6px] pt-2 text-xs font-medium uppercase leading-normal text-neutral-50 transition duration-150 ease-in-out hover:border-neutral-100 hover:bg-neutral-500 hover:bg-opacity-10 hover:text-neutral-100 focus:border-neutral-100 focus:text-neutral-100 focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 active:border-neutral-200 active:text-neutral-200 dark:hover:bg-neutral-100 dark:hover:bg-opacity-10'
                data-te-ripple-init
                data-te-ripple-color='light'
              >
                Get started
              </button> */}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}
```

components/NavBar.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import Link from "next/link";

const NavBar = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <header>
        {/* <!-- Navigation bar --> */}
        <nav
          className='navbar relative flex w-full items-center justify-between bg-white py-2 text-neutral-600 shadow-lg hover:text-neutral-700 focus:text-neutral-700 dark:bg-neutral-600 dark:text-neutral-200 md:flex-wrap md:justify-start'
          data-te-navbar-ref
        >
          <div className='flex w-full flex-wrap items-center justify-between px-3'>
            <div className='flex items-center'>
              {/* <!-- Hamburger menu button --> */}
              <button
                className='border-0 bg-transparent px-2 text-xl leading-none transition-shadow duration-150 ease-in-out hover:text-neutral-700 focus:text-neutral-700 dark:hover:text-white dark:focus:text-white lg:hidden'
                type='button'
                data-te-collapse-init
                data-te-target='#navbarSupportedContentX'
                aria-controls='navbarSupportedContentX'
                aria-expanded='false'
                aria-label='Toggle navigation'
              >
                {/*   <!-- Hamburger menu icon --> */}
                <span className='[&>svg]:w-5'>
                  <svg
                    xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
                    fill='none'
                    viewBox='0 0 24 24'
                    stroke-width='1.5'
                    stroke='currentColor'
                    className='h-7 w-7'
                  >
                    <path
                      stroke-linecap='round'
                      stroke-linejoin='round'
                      d='M3.75 6.75h16.5M3.75 12h16.5m-16.5 5.25h16.5'
                    />
                  </svg>
                </span>
              </button>
            </div>

            {/*  <!-- Navigation links --> */}
            <div
              className='!visible hidden grow basis-[100%] items-center lg:!flex lg:basis-auto'
              id='navbarSupportedContentX'
              data-te-collapse-item
            >
              <ul
                className='mr-auto flex flex-col lg:flex-row'
                data-te-navbar-nav-ref
              >
                <li className='mb-4 lg:mb-0 lg:pr-2' data-te-nav-item-ref>
                  <a
                    className='block transition duration-150 ease-in-out hover:text-neutral-700 focus:text-neutral-700 disabled:text-black/30 dark:hover:text-white dark:focus:text-white lg:p-2 [&.active]:text-black/90'
                    href='#!'
                    data-te-nav-link-ref
                    data-te-ripple-init
                    data-te-ripple-color='light'
                  >
                    <Link href='/'>Home</Link>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li className='mb-4 lg:mb-0 lg:pr-2' data-te-nav-item-ref>
                  <a
                    className='block transition duration-150 ease-in-out hover:text-neutral-700 focus:text-neutral-700 disabled:text-black/30 dark:hover:text-white dark:focus:text-white lg:p-2 [&.active]:text-black/90'
                    href='#!'
                    data-te-nav-link-ref
                    data-te-ripple-init
                    data-te-ripple-color='light'
                  >
                    Features
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li className='mb-4 lg:mb-0 lg:pr-2' data-te-nav-item-ref>
                  <a
                    className='block transition duration-150 ease-in-out hover:text-neutral-700 focus:text-neutral-700 disabled:text-black/30 dark:hover:text-white dark:focus:text-white lg:p-2 [&.active]:text-black/90'
                    href='#!'
                    data-te-nav-link-ref
                    data-te-ripple-init
                    data-te-ripple-color='light'
                  >
                    Pricing
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li className='mb-2 lg:mb-0 lg:pr-2' data-te-nav-item-ref>
                  <a
                    className='block transition duration-150 ease-in-out hover:text-neutral-700 focus:text-neutral-700 disabled:text-black/30 dark:hover:text-white dark:focus:text-white lg:p-2 [&.active]:text-black/90'
                    href='#!'
                    data-te-nav-link-ref
                    data-te-ripple-init
                    data-te-ripple-color='light'
                  >
                    <Link href='/aboutUs'>About</Link>
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
};

export default NavBar;
```

I tried removing all the preset styling but still it does not change and have also tried to give custom properties to navbar in global.css but of no use.

it's just the start of the project so i have not made any much changes to the default app settings of Next JS. Using ESLint, TypeScript and Tailwind CSS & Tailwind Elements

[image: Next App Home Page]

Comment: Seems like you are applying both styling to ".navbar". One with src/global.css and directly with TailwindCSS. Maybe removing the style from global.css will fix it